# Redirect to template after celery task complete

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, celery, django-celery

I use Celery with Django to put my pdf generation in background, while I display a loading page.

But when the task is complete (i.e. my pdf is generated), I want to redirect to the next view which is responsible to send mail and display a friendly confirmation message to the user.

I know i can get the task_postrun or task_success signal, but I can't redirect from there.

I searched for hours but didn't find any solution, any ideas ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways:

1. Ask the server: save the *task_id* in the model where you are storing the PDF, and create an ajax view to check every X seconds if task is completed, the result of this view will determine if it should redirect or still wait for the PDF.

   ```
   result = MyTask.AsyncResult(task_id)
   result.get()
   ```
2. Real-time web: another way is using pusher with [pusher_client_python](https://github.com/pusher/pusher_client_python), when PDF generation is completed (in your PDF creation rutine), make a api call to pusher who will send a notification to the connected client (that one waiting for the result) and will redirect, this approach is more convenient because you don't have to be asking the server every X seconds. You will need to learn about sockets paradigm, but its very easy to implement.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks ! But the first solution seems suboptimal to me, isn't there a way to use celery api or a django feature to redirect ?  
  
As for the second solution, I would rather not use a third party web service for such a simple thing :)

Comment: you need to have the control to the request to make a redirect, after you have made the "generating the document" response page, you dont have the control of this request anymore to make it, you have to ask to the server (1) or do some realtime push (2).

Comment: Thanks, I just went with the ajax request ;)